# CSS Styling a Kanban - resize & re-position DIVs to fit content

Tags: html, css, asp.net, kanban

I have been developing a Kanban board for a generic system we maintain in work. I have the core functionality all working but am getting a little stuck on the styling. The following screenshot shows what I currently have:

[image]

There is a main DIV that contains all the 'columns/containers' and this is styled:

```
.kanban-board {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    display: normal;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This div contains a series of 'containers' - each grey column which is another DIV styled:

```
.kanban-container {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eaebed;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    min-height: calc(50% - 20px);
    display: table;
}
```

and to note - there could be any number of these 'containers' so they currently wrap to the next line as per the above screen shot. Each 'container' DIV contains an UnOrdered sortable List (UL) and this is styled:

```
.kanban-sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 285px;
    display: table-row;
}
```

If you look back to the screenshot, the last 'container' of the first row extends beyond the (min) height of the other containers... Seems okay until the longest is NOT the last in the row:

[image]

Now it just looks rubbish... And I have not a clue on how to get this sorted. I have checked some other Kanban examples and my other option is to just flow off page to the right with an X-Scroll bar - but my current spec requires me to fix this issue.

I hope I have supplied enough info for a quick fix.
BTW - im happy to address any other rookie mistakes I may have made from my example.

**UPDATE**
I have had tried the advice given to use `display: inline-block;`(in the .kanban-container) instead of:

```
float: left;
display: table;
```

And its difficult to see if it has fixed my issue as the auto-resize of the 'containers' height is no longer working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using floats, you'll need a container for each row that clears the previous one. Another way would be to remove the float, and set the .kanban-container to display: inline-block. If you need table properties in that, you'll have to add an inner container, but frankly I'm a little confused by all the styles used here and the !importants that go with them.

```
<div class="kanban-row">
    <div class="kanban-container">
    <div class="kanban-container">
    ...
</div>
<div class="kanban-row">
    ...
```

css:

```
.kanban-row {
    clear: left;
    overflow: hidden; // may not be necessary
}
.kanban-container {
    float: left;
}
```

or (without rows):

```
.kanban-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kjetil. I have updated the question to remove the !important tags... I have not exactly read the "book" on CSS best practices and only dip in from time to time so please excuse any 'noise' in my code. I will investigate your suggestions though... Any working examples would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my comment to what will hopefully be an answer. You may also want to check out CSS display: flex. It's another way to make this work.

Comment: Thanks again...! My initial thought here is that, currently, as the width of each container is definitive - when we resize the browser window the number of containers in a row changes... Do you envisage this to accommodate this behaviour? Again, appreciate the responses dude!

Comment: Then the inline-block option would be best. Try it out. It may slightly change the spacing, but you can fix that.

Comment: Thanks again Kjetil - I have tried it out but the auto-sizing of the containers height is no longer applying... :( I don't suppose you have a hard and fast fix for this? :)

Comment: Another problem I will have to overcome is that the container divs now seem to resize with the browser instead of stay static as they did in the Table example... I have have to re-think this...?! :(

Comment: If you could share a working sample of your code, enough to reproduce the scenarios here, people would be able to assist you better.

Comment: I will see if I can get something up today. :)